# Blank map in result page using MapServer

Tags: mapserver, query, mapfile

I am using MapServer to retrieve the data into my map but I get only a blank page instead of data on the map.

I am using the below query to fetch the data from a PostgreSQL:

```
DATA "the_geom from aoi using unique gid using SRID=2263"
```

Is this the correct way to form the query in the Mapfile?

Comment: Blank page without any error message means usually that there are no data inside the BBOX that is used in the GetMap request. Usually this is caused by some misconfiguration with projections.

Comment: I have a different query in a different layer which works. I have both the layers in the same map file.

Comment: What should I make sure as correct in the map file in order to avoid the misconfiguration with the projection?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Something that may take some getting used to is that it is often (I think usually) better to respond to comments by using the edit button beneath your question to revise it with more details that address the comments from other users.  This way all the information is in one place and potential answerers do not need to read a comment trail to try and understand the question.

Comment: Does using a different TYPE variable matters here. If I have TYPE as POLYGON instead of POINT , does that matter in getting correct projection?

Comment: Please take this as constructive advice on how to get your question answered sooner rather than later.  There is a good [Meta Q&A](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question) that provides suggestions/recommendations about how to maximise your chances of getting a quick and comprehensive answer on GIS SE.

Comment: I dont have a shapefile for this mapping. I just have .sql files. Do I need to generate shape files?

Comment: what version of Mapserver?